# Haskell RSS, mail and XML library choices

Tags: xml, email, haskell, rss, webserver

I've been learning Haskell for some time now and with every new programming language I learn I do a little project that requires working with a mail server and publishing RSS and Atom content. The only problem is, I can't seem to find decent packages for these or at least can't find any reviews of packages.

So I'll ask the community:

Any preferred packages for interacting with a mail server? (IMAP, POP3 etc)

Any preffered packages for publishing an RSS and/or Atom feed? Failing that, any preferred package for general XML?

Any suggestions for a minimalistic, low friction webserver to bind all of that together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask why this question was closed? There are other questions on libraries, both Haskell and in other languages and they aren't closed.

Comment: The `feed` library is a good choice for serious RSS work. For publishing, I quite like `feed-cli`, or `feed` itself.

Comment: @DonStewart we've had problems using the `feed` package to parse feeds in the past, a combination of slow performance, space leaks and incompatibility with real (not exactly RFC compliant) feeds... and so we ended up writing yet another parser based on `xml-enumerator`. One of these days we'll probably port it over to `xml-conduit` and put it up on hackage.

Comment: First of all, thanks to everyone who voted to reopen, made my day.
Second, @NathanHowell if I don't need parsing capabilities, just publishing, is `feed` good enough?

Comment: I'd suspect so, but we don't use it for parsing (which we do a whole lot of) or publishing (which we do none of)... I was responding to the "serious" bit of @dons comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer this question, the [`feed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/feed) package is good for producing rss. For email, folks typically just shell out to the sendmail executable directly. The [`mime-mail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-mail) package provides a wrapper around this along with some additional tools. If you want to *read* email, the typical way is to set up `procmail` or the like, and then use an `mbox` parser to interact with the generated files directly. Two parsers are [`mbox`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mbox) and [`codec-mbox`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/codec-mbox).

If you really want to interact with pop3/imap, you can do the former with [pop3-client](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pop3-client) and the latter with HaskellNet, which is pretty old but apparently works. Example code for using it is available [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/imapget).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Since I only need to do very lightweight work I think I'll use pop3-client but thanks for pointing out the procmail way.