# Send mail to an email address using Yesod

Tags: email, haskell, yesod

I'm unable to find any good documentation or examples of how to send an mail to an email address using Yesod.

More practically, I'll extract the information the user typed inside a simple form (name, age, body of message) and send this information as a mail to an email address.

I'm kind of lost in this task.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three packages I'd recommend you look at:

- [mime-mail](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-mail), which is a package for composing emails and rendering to bytestrings. It can also send via the system `sendmail` executable.
- [mime-mail-ses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-mail-ses), which can send mail from mime-mail via Amazon SES.
- [smtp-mail](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/smtp-mail), which can send mail from mime-mail via an SMTP connection.

There is some discussion about sending email in the [auth chapter of the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I look into these packages, they have methods to send an email (methods that return IO () ). How do you use those methods inside Yesod? When I extract the content of the simple form, I'm inside a Handler which returns a Widget. Where in the code can I send this email?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use liftIO to run an IO action in either the Handler or Widget monads.

Answer (score 4):

Yesod doesn't have mailing functions. You have to use other packages outside Yesod.

Maybe you'd want to check this short answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763447/1744195